# Display modal popup from code behind error

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have a datalist which has an ASP.NET image server control Id="imgCart". Now I want to display a modal pop up when user click on the image button. As every product must have different discription, I need to fill the gridview from the code behind. Below is the code:

```
asp:DataList Id=:ImageList" OnItemCommand="Item_Command" > ItemTemplate > asp:ImageButton Id=: "imgcart"
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Item_Command(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("imgcart");
        string idProduct = img.ToolTip.Trim();
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
    }
```

Everything is working fine, expect the modal pop up is not being displayed.

Code for the Modal-pop up which [I have placed it outside the datalist]

```
 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"
     PopupControlID="PopupPanel" TargetControlID="imgcart" 
    runat="server">
   </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>



  <asp:panel id="PopupPanel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" 
   BorderColor="black" BorderWidth="3px" BackColor="AliceBlue" 
   Height="200px" Width="200px" style="display: none"> 
       <asp:Label ID="lblPopup" runat="server" Text="popup!"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlData" runat="server">
       </asp:DropDownList><br />
                    <br />              
       <asp:Button ID="btnPopupOK" runat="server" Text="Ok" />             
       <asp:Button ID="btnPopupCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />         
     </asp:panel>
```

**Error Message**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   TargetControlID of
>   'ModalPopupExtender1' is not valid. A
>   control with ID 'imgcart' could not be
>   found.

Please help. I want to display modal popup from code behind!!

**Edit1**

When I placed the ajax modalpopup inside the datalist then it is displaying the modalpopup but it is not going to the code behind, I need a code behind event to get the product id.

Comment: What I believe is that it is not able to bind the modal pop up to the imgcart control because there is no such controls in the datalist at runtime, control name displayed like some ctrl_contentplaceholder1.....

Answer (score 3):

Add a button with `Display:none` property.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgcart" runat="server" style="display:none;" />
```

Hope it will help for you.

Comment: @Pankaj Agarwal Thanks for replying but it didn't helped me. I am getting the same error message.

Comment: @Chris: Please put imgcart button outside of DataList.

Comment: @Pankaj Agarwal  I afraid I can't do that, it is the cart image of every product in the datalist, I need to open modal popup when user click on this cart image.

Comment: @Chris: My Means that please create a dummy button like as id="btnDummy" and set TargetControlID="btnDummy" and set btnDummy style display none. btnDummy should be outside of DataList.

Comment: @Pankaj Agarwal  In that case it is working. Now I am sure that the problem is with the Id [i.e. imgcart] because on rumtime it is expecting it as ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageList_ctl01_imgcart

Comment: The IDs of the involved buttons aren't really important.  What's important is getting the ID from the raising event - I'd suggest using CommandArgument for that.

Comment: @Dave But I didn't find CommandArgument in datalist. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry.  What I meant, was you need a better way to get back to the data that you put into the tooltip.  e.Item.DataItem should get you back to your original data item - put the correct property from that into your modal popup.